# Chinese Mathematics Education

Tags: mathematics, united-states, academic-life, working-time, china

I often wonder about Mathematics Education in China, particularly at the late high school and undergraduate level.

In the US, a typical undergraduate math degree will include
lower division:
1-2 years of calculus (3 courses)
different equations (1 course)
linear albegra (1 course)

upper division
1 year of analysis (2 or three courses, real and complex)
1 year of algebra  (2 courses)
and a mix of: number theory, topology, more linear algebra, and so on.

I have heard from Chinese friends and seen on a few websites that Chinese students are often a few years ahead of our pace here in the US. For instance, they have often already started working on analysis and topology in late high school. It seems that they are doing US graduate level work by half way through their undergrad. What's more they are probably better at whatever subject they are learning too based on the sheer effectiveness of their education system.

I am wondering, for all that the romantic values of the US education are worth, why it seems that the Chinese system simply makes better, and frankly, more mathematically intelligent students. It seems that the best Chinese students read more, for longer hours, do more math problems etc. Whether or not this is by their own volition or because they are feeling pressure to do so (as is often case, so it's explained to me), the end result is the same regardless; They spend more time doing math, and they are better at it.

**How can a student in the US honestly hope to learn enough math to be on an equal footing with a student who has worked 50% longer hours, and begun their mathematics education years earlier (if we're also not looking at particular cases of geniuses emerging at a young age in either country, but rather the average intelligent student)?**

Please do share any knowledge, experience, or opinion you have related to these questions. I am a math student doing my undergraduate degree in the US, and I feel my education is not rigorous or thorough enough, despite being at a 
reputably challenging, well regarded institution. Furthermore, when I express my desire to work longer hours than other students, I am met with negative comments about how more work does not mean more knowledge. I think that's just plain wrong, so long as you're remaining healthy.

I have heard similar things about Russia, and even Japan and Korea. Please do share your thoughts.

Thank you for your input.

**Edit and clarification**: I agree with the sentiment that a broader education can help students deal with the real world, so to speak, better than a narrow one can in some respects. But first I'd like to suggest that we can't use the fact that the US was doing the best science in the last century to suggest this system is better. Many of the great discoveries and advancements I think of here in the last century are disqualified from this discussion by two factors. Firstly, the imperial history of the U.S. and its strategic footing during the World Wars allowed it to dominate in almost everything globally, from trade, to military power, to science. Secondly, many of the great advancements I think of in the past century were done by either exceptional geniuses who typically exhibited exceptional abilities at a young age, and furthermore many foreigners who came to the US for the reason above (I'm thinking Von Neumann, Einstein, etc). As the US loses its global dominance, I think that we will see less of this sentiment that the US education system really works exceptionally well in the ways that we imagine and discuss in this thread, and more recognition that other factors were at play. Furthermore, having first hand experience, it really does seem that my Chinese peers are better at math, their knowledge is not shallow in any respect. They work harder than most students here, and know the material better. They spend more time on homework and do more problems in their universities. It's not necessarily the breadth of our education that is responsible, but a combination of the breadth our lack of devotion to long hours and thorough understanding in exchange for serious labor.

Think, Chinese students will get perfect math GRE scores and be rejected from US math programs, while US students rarely if ever get such a score. Yet we still dismiss them as simply having memorized facts for the test. I think this is a big mistake, and will come back to bite the US, and its romantic liberal arts style education.

Comment: I am a tenured mathematician.  I think the single undergraduate course that contributed the most to my professional development was a philosophy class (and it wasn't a logic or philosophy of math class).  Mental flexibility is more important than technical knowledge, and the American system does a good job of encouraging mental flexibility.  (For a famous example - Ed Witten was a History major as an undergrad!)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.But Edward Witten was a prodigy, raised by a physicist father, doing calculus in his preteens. I was hoping to ask in the name of the average intelligent student rather than exceptions.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Mathematics Educators Stack Exchange](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I agree with Alexander: let's avoid this "US vs Chinese system" debate. Just accept the fact that if there are 1000 people swimming the same lane with you, there is very little chance for you to be in the top 1% or so -- whether your competitors are Chinese or your fellow Americans. The best option is to swim a different lane, i.e. to find out how your CV can stand out among 1000 CVs of other technically competent people.

Comment: There have been several studies conparing the educational state of one country with another. One that has a couple of examples is UK with Europe - I will let you have the pleasure of finding them.

Comment: I'm not specifically familiar with Chinese higher education, but you should note that the two factors you cite: study hours and early coverage of advanced topics, can be quite misleading, and in fact often suggest non-rigorous programs that provide useless degrees. For example I deal with lots of international students who think they know linear algebra, having taken it both in HS and UG, but actually didn't cover much beyond matrix algebra. They take many simultaneous classes with shallow depth, and all they do is cram for exams which test memorization.

Comment: China isn't the only example -- mainland European students are, at the end of their undergraduate career, also already at a level halfway through US grad school. It's really a romantic idea that the US education system is particularly good, but that's empirically just not true. (Though one might argue about what exactly "good" means.)

Comment: This can be made into an interesting question, but for now it is "more of a comment, really". Are you asking whether/how workload (measured in hours) affects the quality of an education? Are you asking where the US system differs from the Chinese one? Or are you working backwards from the result (in your case, the claim -- which I cannot verify -- that mathematicians who did their undergraduate degree in China are more successful than US-learned ones) and asking what is making the difference? The former two questions are reasonable, but the last is too broad and depends on unproven claims.

Comment: Darij, I was hoping for an open discussion. In response to others, I see a trend that we only have anecdotal evidence that our system is better. Where is the evidence? I think I am leaning towards Wolfgang's opinion here. See my edit to my post please. Thank you all sincerely for your thoughts.

Comment: The StackExchange family of sites is a Q&A format, not a discussion forum. An "open discussion" such as what you're looking for doesn't fit well here. However, if you have a specific question about some aspect of Chinese or US mathematics education, you can ask it here or in the [matheducators](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com) stack.

Comment: As said above, this is not a discussion forum. This question should be closed as off-topic.

Comment: Well then please provide answers to the questions in my post. No need to close the question because of a comment I provided after posting.

Comment: American students spend less time in school, period, starting in kindergarten. There are a bunch of reasons this is hard to change.

Comment: Still, this question is too verbose. If you have a precise question, ask it without all that fluff. Your edit in particular adds precisely nothing, it's just a rant about how the US "loses its global dominance" and blah blah blah.

Comment: Thank you for the genuine answers. Those speculating that the answers will be rubbish have needlessly fulfilled their own prophecy. Any more answers to the question, or opinions about the solution for an American student are appreciated.

Comment: _"Firstly, the imperial history of the U.S. and its strategic footing during the World Wars allowed it to dominate in almost everything globally, from trade, to military power, to science. "_ Ignores the common cause. Much more likely that the same cultural factors led to US success in other areas as well as in education. The US was not the only "imperial" country, nor the only remote former colony which survived WW2 intact, nor the only place emigrants could choose to go, nor the only...

Comment: @Sam if you don't like anecdotal evidence (certainly a worthwhile stance), I'd suggest not basing your own question on it. Who are these Chinese friends and peers you are citing anyway? A random sampling of students in China, or a biased sample who made it to the US or the world stage?

Comment: A Simple Algorithm, to answer your questions, I was told this these things as you mention, and then verified that the programs do in fact work at a more rigorous pace. That is, they start earlier (analysis and topology in high school) and work more hours (more intensive programs, see peking uni's math webpage). It is also widely reported that Chinese score higher on mathematics aptitude tests. Thank you for the responses. Pardon me if that was not clear.

Comment: @Sam in other words you started with a conclusion then found evidence to support it. China probably has a comparable number of universities to the US (thousands) and a comparable number of students in them (millions, despite 4x the population, meaning a lot more selectivity is possible). I can already tell you that nothing you say will universally hold true about the US schools. For example I have personally attended a school that was very easy as well as a school that was very demanding (look for the ones with the highest suicide rates).

Comment: I disagree, with respect. I think rather some people may be ignoring evidence, and imagining what our conclusion should be based on how things are in the US. The evidence is abundant and clear, the Chinese government has strict curriculum standards for all schools in mathematics, and has for years. Sure some schools may not be so great as others, but the national laws, university programs, and the data speak for themselves. I hope to know how a dissatisfied American student is supposed to respond in the opinion of others, as I mention in my post.

Comment: @Sam as someone who's field is actually statistics, I see no real evidence yet. What data? The number of hours spent at cramming school in the evening? This is your supposed cause, not the effect you claim (higher performance). And every country has curriculum standards of some variety, how do you compare them? The age at which a class title appears on a transcript? I already noted how that is useless. You need a way to compare outcomes of the classes. Perhaps math placement test results at top universities here, if they share that info by country of applicant.

Comment: As I have already mentioned above, there are various aptitude tests that can be found with a quick google search, GRE data is widely available, I just mentioned the data that is the Chinese national curriculum standards, university standards, all of which are readily available to view online. I think it's pretty clear how you compare them... More math education at an earlier age, more intensive curriculum lead to to higher scores and aptitude. Who would have guessed? I realize this discussion may not be productive, and have accepted an answer to the question. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Sam it would be a tad more productive if we didn't start with the answer and ask others to do our research. Note that I have never argued for a particular ranking, only that your logic is unconvincing and in fact backward. I would expect narrow comparisons like theoretical math to potentially favor central communist systems that emphasize it. But I'm not going to be convinced by bad arguments that also describe the worst systems.

Comment: @Sam - One perspective that I have heard from a tenured math professor is that whereas European math education tends to be more standardized, there are more options for the types of math classes you can take as an undergrad in the U.S. For example there may be 3 different types of linear algebra classes, depending on your background and goals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can a student in the US honestly hope to learn enough math to be on an equal footing with a student who has worked 50% longer hours, and begun their mathematics education years earlier (if we're also not looking at particular cases of geniuses emerging at a young age in either country, but rather the average intelligent student)?

Your question contains a flawed premise, which is that in order to succeed in your studies and/or career you need to be (or that it even makes sense to ask if you are or are not) “on equal footing” with some arbitrary group of students.

Empirically, every year a couple of thousand students in the US graduate with a PhD in the mathematical sciences, about half of them US citizens (see [here](https://www.ams.org/Excerpt_PhDs_Demographics.pdf)). **It is an empirical fact** that many of those US mathematicians go on to extremely successful careers in academia and elsewhere. We can argue from now until next week about the philosophical differences between US, Chinese and other nations’ education systems, but it seems pointless to argue with facts. The evidence simply suggests that American-educated mathematicians compete just fine with those educated outside the US. So the answer to your “How can a student in the US hope ...” is: they can certainly hope it, because that is what the reality on the ground is telling them.

Second, let me address the “on equal footing” issue. What comes to mind here is the notion of [comparative advantage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparative_advantage) from economics - the idea that people in different places are better at producing different goods - I will apply it in the case when the “goods” are mathematical results rather than economic foods. Let’s assume for the sake of discussion that Chinese mathematics students indeed study and work harder than their US counterparts. I don’t know if this is true, but I have heard some similar things in other contexts (for example that classical music prodigies in China work themselves half to death from a young age, and as a result achieve levels of virtuosity that western musicians find essentially impossible to match) so it wouldn’t surprise me if it were true. Now, as it happens I agree with you that a person who works harder will end up knowing more and knowing the material better than someone who doesn’t work as hard. That’s absolutely true, and if you want to be successful, being a hard worker is a terrific advantage.

But now, guess what? Knowing more does not *necessarily* translate to being more successful. It turns out that American students enjoy their own set of comparative advantages over those from many other nations, very probably including China. For example: the environment in which American students are raised and educated is more economically prosperous, safe, healthy, and (to some extent) psychologically supportive than those in many other countries. Their country is one that famously encourages freedom of thought and of speech, creativity, innovation, risk-taking, and many other values that are positively correlated with personal and national success. Even in the limited context of mathematics, I feel reasonably confident in estimating that all of those circumstances can add up to quite a significant comparative advantage, that enables those students to produce certain kinds of high quality mathematics that their Chinese and other peers are not able to produce.

The bottom line is: hard work is important; cramming your head full of facts and knowledge is important; but they are not the *only* important things. There is much new work in mathematics that can be better done (or in some cases can only be done) by someone who is very creative and has a flexible and original mind than by someone who works extremely hard and knows a lot but isn’t as imaginative or creative or willing to take risks. (And conversely, someone who works hard and knows a lot can do things that a “lazy” but super-creative person cannot do. The principle of comparative advantage works both ways.)

Focus on your advantages, and you will be fine.

Comment: I appreciate your input, especially with respect to the advantages of each individual. I am skeptical of whether the advantage that an American or similar culture has (sounds like American exceptionalism to some extent) is really that of flexibility, creativity, etc, or just as you allude to, favorably tilted starting conditions in life and a less competitive job market, but I very well may just not understand what the reality of the situation is for working mathematician. Regardless, you answered the question .The bit about creativity seems important. Thank you for the thoughtful answer, Dan!

Comment: "that enable those students to produce certain kinds of high quality mathematics that their Chinese and other peers are not able to produce." This seems important. I am curious to know more about this idea of different qualities of mathematics, so to speak. I can imagine what you're talking about, but please do message me (or post here) if you can suggest further reading about this.

Comment: @Sam you’re welcome. To be clear, I’m by no means an exceptionalist of any sort. There are many great nations in the world, each of which can inspire us to be better in some ways that are unique to it. And some countries do regard mathematics more highly in their culture and traditions than the United States, and as a result produce more than their fair share of excellent mathematicians. Again, this isn’t necessarily correlated with working long hours, so I wouldn’t say that’s the thing one should obsess about.

Comment: @Sam I don’t have any further reading - these are intuitive and entirely speculative thoughts based on my personal experience.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm. Are apples better or are oranges better? Hmmm.

It is difficult to compare educational systems with such a narrow focus as is done in the question. Where do we study Linear Algebra? Ultimately there are more important questions. These questions are attempted to be answered through a somewhat ill formed national educational set of objectives that may be driven centrally (China) or widely distributed (US).

In the US, there are problems with the pre-college education system due to a lack of resources and an unwillingness of politicians to raise taxes or to think creatively about how to provide those resources. More could be done, if more money could be provided and if it wasn't seen as a political strategy to attack teachers, partly because they have traditionally had strong unions.

At the undergraduate level in the US, the philosophy is that the education should be very broad. One doesn't only study mathematics if your major is math. You also study history, philosophy, language, sociology, art and music (possibly), literature, and other things.

At the masters level in the US, the study narrows, but not so much as in other places. One typically studies the field intensively, but mathematics is, itself, a broad field. Insight in algebra is quite different from insight into analysis. Some insights carry over, but not all.

At the doctoral level in the US, as is true elsewhere, one studies a small part of a field very intensively and focuses on research in that field and extending what is known there. Some MS programs start on this narrowing, but not all.

In the US, each university, generally speaking, defines its own curriculum. Within fields, the faculty *realizes* a curriculum and there is generally fairly wide acceptance about what is possible. Pre college education is normally defined at the State level, with Michigan and New Jersey, perhaps, having quite different standards.

In some other countries the educational system is very hierarchical with, in theory, every student studying the same things at the same age. But even there, differences of implementation can cause differences of outcome.

But what is better?

That depends on what you are trying to achieve. If your goal is to create narrowly educated "technocrats" who don't know or care much about life then a narrow education is what would be preferred. But if you want, instead, to educate the "whole person" then a broad education is better overall, even if it takes longer to develop technical skills.

But, as a CS professor, I always considered it much more important to understand *what should be built* rather than *how to build a given thing*. If you don't understand the *should* you can do great damage to the world (take note Facebook, Twitter, ...).

Traditionally this broad educational system has served the US pretty well. In the 20th and early 21st centuries, many (most?) of the world's most important scientific discoveries were done here, though often enough by immigrants who studied elsewhere. I note that that is now changing, but I also note that US education is receiving even less support - witness too many colleges depending far too much on loan supported student tuitions, rather than grants or straightforward, tax supported, funding.

I used to warn people in highly technical fields who focused too much on details, that, eventually, the history and philosophy majors who knew nothing of what they, themselves, did, would be their employers. The history and philosophy majors took a broader view and could better judge what was important. Even in CS courses, I predicted that the students that asked *why* would have a better future than those who could only ask *how*.

Comment: For all the traditional (and non-traditional) American focus on breadth in undergraduate studies, I'm seeing little of it manifest when I have a conversation with mathematicians who studied in the US. Are they sitting in all those history classes and not learning anything? Does it all get forgotten when the sheepskin arrives? Am I only picking up European cultural references and are they only learning non-European culture? I know you're *supposed* to broaden horizons rather than hear answers in those kinds of classes, but the average European academic seems to have broader horizons, ...

Comment: ... at least to me, than the average American one. And as far as independent thinking is concerned, my impression is that it cannot be learned from any class, but European academia, with its sink-or-swim structure, is at least good at filtering out the non-independent thinkers. And in mathematics, American universities are definitely **not** teaching independent thinking when they only start with proofs in the 2nd or 3rd year.

Comment: @darijgrinberg What does "independent thinker" mean? As far as sink-or-swim academic culture goes, it's mostly an effective filter for students from educationally privileged families. American higher ed culture (at least nominally) recognizes that this is a bad thing.

Comment: "Independent thinker" means a whole cluster of things; on the level of (say) maths graduate students it includes an ability to figure out when to stop reading and start writing; what to learn and what to re-do; how to spot connections between different subjects and what to make out of them; more generally, the ability to take the driver's instead of the passenger's seat. These are hard to learn from any structured class-like activities -- stacking extra breadth requirements in particular is unlikely to be useless; but at least in mathematics, there is one obvious thing that you can do to ...

Comment: ... set this independence process in motion, and that's starting proof-based classes early. I'm not saying the European system is generally very good (the cost-benefit ratio is unbeatable, but I'm not going to claim that freshmen classes with 1000 students, half of whom are only seeing the lecturer through a video screen, are superior to US offerings), but this is something it is clearly good at, while US universities for some reason aren't even trying. Linear algebra is another thing (undergrads get 2 classes of LA in Germany and 1 in the US, and it *shows*).

Comment: I think all of these fluffy factors such as creativity and "independent thinking" (which as math people, I would expect us all to find frustratingly subjective) are proxies for higher levels on Bloom's taxonomy. There may be a lot of content in a cramming system, but if one counts problems at higher cognitive levels as additional material, fast-moving memorization based systems actually skip tons of content.